# setSinkId() function throws error in Electron App

Tags: javascript, html, electron, html5-audio

I am trying to develop an app which plays audio and includes the function to change audio devices. My only problem is when I try to use the `setSinkId()` function, it gives me a DOMException AbortError with the message 'The operation could not be performed and was aborted'. I have tried the exact same code in the latest version of Chrome and it allows me to set the sinkId without any issues. Here's my code:

```
     var promise = audio.setSinkId(deviceID);

     promise.then(function(result) {
         console.log('Audio output device sink ID is ' + deviceID);
     }, function(e) {
         console.log('Error: ' + e.name + ' - ' + e.message);
     });
```

I have tryed passing the `AudioOutputDevices` parameter through the `enableBlinkFeatures` when I setup the browser window but this doesn't make and difference.

Comment: In which browser does it throw an error? setSinkId is not supported by all browsers yet. Although, I must admit that I would expect a different error message on browsers not supporting it yet. You can check the list of supported browsers for this function on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement.

Comment: In my case when the user of my web application set the mic off(as input device) and then tried to change the output device then the user received this error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation could not be performed and was aborted". Does it help you?

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain and I had the same question during my development. I didn't solve it in straight way. I can only suggest to check a few things regarding your source HTML element reference.

1) Is the `srcObject` set correctly?
Before first time use `setSinkId()`, check if

```
audio.srcObject = stream;
```

2) Check if `setSinkId()` event is not interrupted by `pause()`, `play()` or `load()` events. Remember that `setSinkId()` is a promise.

```
await audio.setSinkId(selectedId);
audio.play();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to this old-reported issue. It's been on hold for years.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=697877

Remember that for getting visibility on chromium, you should “Start" it with your Google account to help to the Chromium team to understand its importance.